# PlantUML Usecase for Actor as member Type

Tags: uml, plantuml

I have a use case where a member would have different roles. How could this be expressed in a PlantUml UseCase. I have the following syntax:

```
  @startuml

  actor Member 

  memberTypeA --|> Member
  memberTypeB --|> Member
  memberTypeC --|> Member

  @enduml
```

Is this correct? IF not how can I define a role?

Comment: You might get a better answer in [PlantUML.com's Q&A forum](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/qa/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems good but the only reason for modellin several user is to have each of them associated to a different UseCase as depicted below.

[image]